# Mark careers job openings as being 'favorite'?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, bookmarks

I can't find a favorite button for job openings over at [careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) so I'll guess there isn't one.

I would like to propose this feature, so that I can get notified on changes et.c.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi Frank - it's on the road map, <strike>exact implementation date t.b.d.</strike> implemented as of last week.