# StackOverflow Careers: Add ability to search by career level?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, jobs, search

For example, I want to search all **entry-level** software engineer jobs in a particular city. If would be really nice to be able to filter my job search by career level. 
No sense in sifting through a bunch of jobs that I'm unqualified for as a recent graduate. You could simply have a drop down menu which would be optional in the search.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! For now I've marked it as declined, not because it's a bad suggestion but for the reasons Jon mentions below. If we have a sudden flash of inspiration we may well revisit this though.

Answer (score 4):

I agree that this would be a nice feature, however it's very difficult for either the employer or the candidates to quantify the different levels. Is "intermediate" at least 3 years of experience or 4? What's the cutoff?

I was going to counterpropose searching by years of experience, but even that is difficult to build in, because employers may need multiple different levels of experience for the same job -- this can't really be aggregated into a meaningful single number.

You just have to bite the bullet and read each job description. Besides, *only you can know what is and isn't a good fit for you.* If you keep up with it, you'll only have to read the new ones, and (soon) [favourite the ones you're interested in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67664/mark-careers-job-openings-as-being-favorite).